# How to Run Process Manager as Super User

Tags: permissions, sudo, process

I am trying to run an API on an Orange Pi. It is running Ubuntu and the API process is running via Node.js Express.

I would like the process to automatically start running when the computer boots up, and I would like it to have sudo permissions.

This process can be done manually with `sudo pm2 start process_name`, however this is not automatic.

I ran a command `sudo chown orangepi:orangepi/.pm2/rpc.sock /home/orangepi/.pm2/pub.sock` but I'm not sure if it is behaving properly.

How would I get this process to start when the device is booted?

How do I grant this process permanent sudo permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I get this process to start when the device is booted?

1. create a service (I used `pm2.service` as example)
2. place service in `/etc/systemd/system/`.
3. enable the service:

   ```
   chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/pm2.service
   systemctl daemon-reload
   systemctl pm2.service
   ```

If the 3rd command is error free system will load the service when booting.

> How do I grant this process permanent sudo permissions?

You don't. "sudo" is only for your admin user. Not for systemd as this is done by root.

Comment: I'm not sure about the terminology, but can I set to permanently run this process as root?

Comment: services (/systemd) are done with user root yes.

Comment: OK. Is the `pm2.sevice` a file that lists bash commands? I'm having trouble finding docs for creating a service.